# How to use agent referrer in codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

In codeigniter 3 it's

```
$test = $this->agent->referrer();
```

How to do it in codeigniter 4?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to find the agent details :

```
$agent = $this->request->getUserAgent();
```

Look at the following link for the reference :
https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/user_agent.html

Answer (score 1):

If within the controller:

```
$this->request->getUserAgent()->getReferrer()
```

Anywhere else where you don't have direct access to the request object

```
\Config\Services::request()->getUserAgent()->getReferrer()
```